# Changing windows width with JQuery without reloading the page again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JQuery rotator in my website with a slides images and I want to make the website responsive. I'm using CSS media queries to do it. I want to change the slide width (which defines in JS) when the windows width is less than 800px.
So long, I did  something like this:

```
var responsiveSlideWidth;

if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    responsiveSlideWidth = 700;
}
else {
    responsiveSlideWidth = 960;
}


var defaults = {
    container: '.rotatorWrapper',
    animationduration: 1000,
    slideWidth: responsiveSlideWidth
};
```

The problem is that it is working just after page reload. Thats means: if I resize the window size its is not working until I reload the page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT: My full code:

```
 (function ($) {

    $.fn.Rotator = function (options) {

        var responsiveSlideWidth;

        if ($(window).width() < 800) {
            responsiveSlideWidth = 700;
        }
        else {
            responsiveSlideWidth = 960;
        }


        var defaults = {
            container: '.rotatorWrapper',
            animationduration: 1000,
            slideWidth: responsiveSlideWidth
        };

        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        elm = this;
        var pageIndex = 0,
            slideCount = 0;



        var _init = function () {
            slideCount = elm.find(options.container).children().children().length;
            elm.find(options.container).children().width(slideCount * options.slideWidth);
            _bindEvents();
            _togglePager();
        };


        var _bindEvents = function () {
            var jElm = $(elm);
            jElm.find('.prev').on('click', _previous);
            jElm.find('.next').on('click', _next);
        };

        var _next = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (pageIndex >= 0 && pageIndex < slideCount - 1) {
                pageIndex++;

                elm.find(options.container).children().animate({
                    left: "-=" + options.slideWidth
                }, options.animationduration);
            }

            _togglePager();
        };

        var _previous = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (pageIndex <= slideCount) {
                pageIndex--;
                elm.find(options.container).children().animate({
                    left: "+=" + options.slideWidth
                }, options.animationduration);
            }
            _togglePager();
        };

        var _togglePager = function () {
            var $elm = $(elm);
            var prev = $elm.find('.prev');
            var next = $elm.find('.next');

            console.log('slide count' + pageIndex + ' Page Index' + pageIndex)

            if (pageIndex >= slideCount - 1) {
                next.hide();
            } else {
                next.show();
            }

            if (pageIndex <= 0) {
                prev.hide();
            } else {
                prev.show();
            }
        }

        return _init(elm);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you'd need to refire on the size change event. can you show your full code. what are you doing with your config object?

Comment: I would suggest that you use jQuery cycle2 plugin instead. I was able to make it work with responsive layouts (see [autoheight demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/autoheight.php))